# Generating PDFs from HTML with data fetched from JSON file

Tags: html, node.js, express

I am new to coding and I only know the basics of Node.js and I'm stuck at a point. I have extracted details of thousands users from a text file and stored it into a JSON file and I have also created an html template which will show a single user's details in a presentable way.
I have tried sending single user data using index no. from the JSON file and fetching that data in html template file and then generating pdf.
I want to generate pdfs of all the users from that JSON file, I don't know how to do this repeatedly until all the pdf files are generated.
Please help!! need some ideas.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("userTemplate.html", {
      root: path.join(__dirname, "../public"),
    });
  });

 app.get("/data", (req, res) => {
    res.send(usersJSONdata[0]);
  });
```

Comment: if you only need to create a pdf using node in your express server, then simply use PDFkit, but if you want to include pdf with data visualization, containing a lot of SVGs, then go for Puppeteer and headless Chrome